# Word meaning: "of experience"?

Tags: adjectives

I have wondered for years if there is an (adjective?) form of the word: "experience".  Obviously, I'm not too much of a grammar Nazi, as I'm not even sure if this would even be an adjective.  But, that's why I'm here; to expand my vocabulary and enhance my grammar.

Anyway, it seems like the word I'm looking for would be "experiential" - or something meaning "of experience".  I see that I didn't get a spelling error when I typed that, so that might be some indication.  Thanks and sorry if this is the most ridiculous question you've ever seen.

Comment: _experiential_ is certainly a proper word. You can look it up in a dictionary to see if means what you're looking for. Could you give an example of how you'd like to use the word you're looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to think at what point I started thinking about this word.  I think the context was something like:  "I know this because of experiential evidence" - or something.  I think I was writing an essay and got to the point where I'd have to use that word for my sentence to make sense.  I can't remember what I did - probably re-worded.

Comment: That seems to be a correct use of the word.

Comment: Probably you are referring to  empirical evidence.

Comment: The adjective that comes to my mind is *experienced*.  Consider clarifying just what you mean, which would presumably exclude *experienced*.

Answer (score 2):

*Experiential* is indeed a word with the general meaning you are looking for, but **empirical**, which Google defines as "based on, concerned with, or verifiable by observation or experience rather than theory or pure logic," is probably a better fit for the context you provided.  *Empirical evidence* is a frequently used phrase in the worlds of science and philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

As a complementary example to Chris Sunami's answer, please note that **empirical** does not cover the totality of, nor necessarily imply, the ***experiential***.

Considering his answer as a start, we have the adjectival:

> *Empirical* knowledge (also, but probably less frequent, *empiric* knowledge).

and we have

> *Experiential* knowledge.

Regardless of any particular philosophical worldview, *experiential* knowledge or understanding is considered by many (but not all!) to be much more encompassing than empiric knowledge. As a (merely) physical-based perception, knowledge derived from an empirical perspective could be considered as a *subset* of experience.

So when you have empirical knowledge based on observations, say in a laboratory experiment, you are also experiencing something. But you can also have a dream, say, which is not at all empirical knowledge (in the typical sense of the word, empiric) - but you experience it nonetheless.

(Although many forms of experience exist, not all of which are empiric, discussions about that would veer promptly off topic, into deep epistemology - the purview of philosophy.SE)

Comment: This is true.  However, it wasn't clear to me from the original question whether the OP was seeking a word with a wider or a more narrow scope.

Comment: @ChrisSunami - understood... I need to edit my answer 'counter example' comes off harsh, which wasn't intended!